# Custom Notification is not displayed on android 12

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

I have a problem with my notification code, in my device with Android 9 It works good but not in Android 12. I notice that maybe It's something related to the RemoteViews but I'm not sure.

This is my code:

object NotificationUtils {

```
private fun createNotification(context: Context, activity: Activity, layout: Int, channelId: String ): Notification {


    return NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
        .setCustomContentView(RemoteViews(activity.packageName, layout))
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo_alfred_sin_texto)
        .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.greenCrusoe))
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .build()
}


fun executeNotification(
    context: Context, notificationId: Int, activity: Activity, layout: Int, channelId: String) {
    val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
    notificationManager
        .notify(notificationId, createNotification(context, activity, layout, channelId))
}


fun createNotificationChannel(channelId : String, channelName: String, activity: Activity){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId,
            channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            .apply {
                lightColor = Color.RED
                enableLights(true)
            }
        val manager = activity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}
```

}

first of all I'm calling createNotificationChannel() and then executeNotification who calls createNotification function.

And here is the xml that I'm passing to my createNotification function:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/greenCrusoe"
app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/common_max_margin_padding_value">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_checkcheck_white"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_margin_value" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_successfully_notification"
    style="@style/textViewTitleStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingVertical="@dimen/common_min_margin_value"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/common_min_margin_value"
    android:text="@string/not_changed_pin_success_text"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Comment: Have you find solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification#create_a_fully_custom_notification_layout

As indicated in the link :

> "Note: Starting with Android 12 (API level 31), apps targeting Android
> 12 or newer are no longer able to create fully custom notifications.
> Instead, the system applies a standard template nearly identical to
> the behavior of Notification.DecoratedCustomViewStyle."

Comment: Although, there are apps that are still able to do that. Android 13 and they still show fully custom notifications.
https://postimg.cc/nCFnz4h9
I wonder how they are doing it?

Answer (score 2):

try using:

```
setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
```

it worked for me

Comment: val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MyVoiceRecorder.CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
            .setCustomContentView(remoteView)
       .setForegroundServiceBehavior(NotificationCompat.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE)
            .build()